# Where can I get P4Win software?

Tags: perforce

I like P4Win than P4V but it seems P4Win is not available in perforce.com. 
Can anybody tell me where can I get P4Win?

Answer (score 4):

Yes Perforce have discontinued P4Win, the replacement being P4V. The last version they released is available from perforce.com here:

ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r08.1/bin.ntx86/p4winst.exe

Of course it may not function correctly or some of the newer features of the perforce server such as streams will be unavailable.